# How to manipulate http GET request integer parameters?

Tags: java, html, http, jsp, get

I'm trying to multiply two values which are parameters which I get from a previous page. I know that I can display them separately with:

```
<p> val1: <%= request.getParameter( "val1" ) %> </p>
```

and

```
<p> val2: <%= request.getParameter( "val2" ) %> </p>
```

however when carrying out the arithmetic operation of multiplying to work out the product of these two values, the below attempt which I've tried does not work so I know this approach is incorrect

```
<p>product: (<%= request.getParameter( "val1" ) %> * <%= request.getParameter( "val2" ) %>)</p>
```

Comment: try `<p>product: (<%= request.getParameter( "val1" )  *  request.getParameter( "val2" ) %>)</p>`

Comment: The tag `<%= %>` is used with different languages. What's yours ?

Comment: I receive the error: `Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String'`   and I am using javascript

Comment: @KBell javascript

Comment: @sh.learner According to the error you get : you're in a **Java** context (which is not JavaScript) : http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: @KBell apologies, there was some confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error you get, it seems you're using Java so you should cast integer this way :

```
<p>product: (<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("val1")) * Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("val2")) %>)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these symbols you're using are for ASPX pages, the answer would be a cast to *int*.

```
<p>product: (<%= (int)request.getParameter("val1") %> * <%= (int)request.getParameter("val2") %>)</p>
```

Comment: I received the error `Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.String' to 'int'`